# Document Similarity using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, topic-modeling

I am new to both TensorFlow and also Document Similarity / Topic Modeling therefore I apologize if my questions don't make complete sense.

From my limited understanding, topic modelling is done using algorithms such as LSA,LDA,etc. I have seen code using gensim and LSA but the time to train is very high for the large set of documents I have in mind. Consequently the CPU and RAM resources are very heavy.

Tensorflow doesn't seem to have a native LSA or LDA implementation.

I would appreciate an opinion on :

- Would LDA implemented using Tensorflow have a better performance than implemented using gensim?
- Could someone tell me of other Tensorflow primitives that I should look at for document similarity rather than LDA?

Once again I am sorry if my questions are too vague and do not cover sufficient information to give a proper response. I am new to this domain and I would appreciate any directions someone could point me to.

Thank you for your time.

Regards,
Jeetu

Comment: As far as I know, TensorFlow does not currently have any in built functionality for LDA. However, it does have word2vec (as does Gensim) - if you really want to use TensorFlow you could use word2vec and understand your documents better through word embeddings; you could then visualise these word embeddings using t-SNE. I appreciate this isn't document comparison, but it's a start.